# Git - how to get Pull Request (PR not merged to master) number from commit hash

Tags: git, pull-request

I want to get a PR number from commit hash, but PR is not merged yet.

If PR is merged I can get the PR number using following command which I found [here](https://coderwall.com/p/kxb7kg/find-a-pull-request-given-the-commit-sha)

```
git log --merges --ancestry-path --oneline XXXXXXX..master | grep 'pull request' | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $5 }'
```

But I need to PR number which is not merged. Please help.

More details - following are the steps to describe the scenario

1. git clone some_repo
2. git checkout -b new_branch
3. Make changes and commit the code to new_branch
4. Note the commit sha - (which will be used to get PR number after step 5)
5. Now create new Pull Request (but do not merge to master yet)

Answer (score 0):

> I do not have control over PR creation.
>   PR will be created by some user and I will be running CI on top of it before merging, where I need the PR number.

That means the CI will fetch the branches, and you need to configure it (for instance a Jenkins job) in order to [fetch the PR branches](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/):

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

That will give you all the `pull/xxx` PR branches, with xxx being the PR number you are looking for.

Comment: I do not have control over PR creation. PR will be created by some user and I will be running CI on top of it before merging, where I need the PR number.

Comment: @ShriganeshShintre OK, I have rewritten the answer accordingly.